# Using add_theme_support inside a plugin

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, post-thumbnails

I've created a custom post type as a plugin and released it into the repository. One of the core features involves using a featured image. I've added `thumbnail` to `$supports` in `register_post_type()`, so the meta box shows up in the Administration Panel. I'm also hooking into `after_setup_theme` and calling `add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' )`, but I don't think it's taking affect.

The codex says [you have to call it from the theme's functions.php file](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_theme_support), but if that's true then it'll only work if the user's theme calls `add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' )` (which would cover *all* post types. If the theme doesn't call it, or only calls it on a specific type, then it won't work.

Does anyone see a way around this problem?

Comment: try hooking the `add_theme_support`  function to `init` with a low priority (99999)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried that but it didn't work.

Comment: Please move your solution to a separate answer, that would be more in line with site's mechanics. Btw are you sure you are not breaking case when support is enabled for all post types (simply `true`) ? Your code looks like it will overwrite it with your CPT alone.

Comment: You're right, I fixed that and moved it to a separate answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are comments in core code that this should be improved, but they are there for a while already. Basically there is no native function to add or remove *part* of some feature, only feature altogether.

Doing it manually would be running something like this after theme is done (late on `after_setup_theme` hook):

```
function add_thumbnails_for_cpt() {

    global $_wp_theme_features;

    if( empty($_wp_theme_features['post-thumbnails']) )
        $_wp_theme_features['post-thumbnails'] = array( array('your-cpt') );

    elseif( true === $_wp_theme_features['post-thumbnails'])
        return;

    elseif( is_array($_wp_theme_features['post-thumbnails'][0]) )
        $_wp_theme_features['post-thumbnails'][0][] = 'your-cpt';
}
```

Comment: You can use get_theme_support() instead of working directly with the global. If I do a var_dump on the global or the return of get_theme_support() they're both NULL, though. I've tried with `init` and `after_setup_theme` with a priority of 99.

Comment: Ah, I think I got it. The theme I was testing with hadn't set anything with it, so it was supposed to be null...

Answer (score 6):

This is what I ended up using, which is a modified version of Rarst's answer

```
public function addFeaturedImageSupport()
{
    $supportedTypes = get_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );

    if( $supportedTypes === false )
        add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( self::POST_TYPE ) );               
    elseif( is_array( $supportedTypes ) )
    {
        $supportedTypes[0][] = self::POST_TYPE;
        add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', $supportedTypes[0] );
    }
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme',    array( $this, 'addFeaturedImageSupport' ), 11 );
```