# add_theme_support using a plugin

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, add-theme-support

I want to create a theme specific plugin for the opern-sourced [Bootstrap Genesis](https://github.com/salcode/bootstrap-genesis) theme where I can use the `add_theme_support` function to add or remove several mini plugins or theme modules/features that I have in a plugin subfolder. I found [this question here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/23839/using-add-theme-support-inside-a-plugin), but could not figure it out based on the accepted answer.

**So the plugin structure would look like this:**

```
themeplugin/
├── addons/
│   ├── addon1.php
│   ├── addon2.php
│   └── addon3.php
└── themeplugin.php
```

**The main plugin file, lets call it `themeplugin.php` would be this:**

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name:       My Theme Name Addons
Plugin URI:        https://example.com
Description:       A collection of mini plugins/addons to apply specific changes.
Version:           1.0
Author:            Author Name
Author URI:        https://example.com/author
License:           MIT License
License URI:       http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT
*/

function load_themename_addons() {
  foreach (glob(__DIR__ . '/addons/*.php') as $file) {
    if (current_theme_supports('themename-' . basename($file, '.php'))) {
      require_once $file;
    }
  }
}
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'load_themename_addons');
```

Then in my `functions.php` I could enable these plugin features/addons by adding theme support, by using each addons filename:

```
<?php
/* functions.php */
add_theme_support('themename-addon1.php');
add_theme_support('themename-addon1.php');
add_theme_support('themename-addon1.php');
```

However, this doesn't work and I can't seem to figure out what I'm missing... When I remove the theme support check it works fine:

```
function load_themename_addons() {
  foreach (glob(__DIR__ . '/addons/*.php') as $file) {
      require_once $file;
  }
}
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'load_themename_addons');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out after playing with [Rarsts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/847/rarst) answer [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/23841/43806).

**[Here is what I ended up with](https://github.com/bryanwillis/bootstrap-genesis-addons):**

```
 <?php
    /*
    Plugin Name:       Bootstrap Genesis Addons
    Plugin URI:        https://github.com/bryanwillis/bootstrap-genesis-addons
    Description:       A collection of mini plugins/addons to apply specific changes to my site.
    Version:           1.0
    Author:            Bryan Willis
    Author URI:        https://github.com/bryanwillis/
    License:           MIT License
    License URI:       http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT
    */


function bootstrap_genesis_addons() {
  global $_wp_theme_features;
  foreach (glob(__DIR__ . '/addons/*.php') as $file) {
    $feature = 'bsg-' . basename($file, '.php');
    if (isset($_wp_theme_features[$feature])) {
      require_once $file;
    }
  }
}
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'bootstrap_genesis_addons', 100);
```

**The theme plugin should follow this file structure:**

```
bsg-addons/
├── addons/
│   ├── foo.php
│   ├── bar.php
│   └── baz.php
└── bsg-addons.php
```

All addons should be added in a subfolder called addons with a unique name for each file.



**Last [add theme support](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_theme_support) the same way you would anything else:**

```
add_theme_support('bsg-foo');
```

Where the above example theme support name "bsg-" + "foo" where *"foo"* is one of the filenames basename you created in the addons folder: `bsg-addons/addons/foo.php`

**It seems to work great and is a lot cleaner in my opinion than adding a bunch of unnecessary data to the database to perform the activations / deactivations of modules or theme specific features like custom post types. It also works for adding entire plugins directly into your theme.**